# C++: Create derived instance by 'extending?' base instance / implement downcast?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class which is essentially a container:

```
class SimpleContainer {
   public:  
       // Various accessor methods / iterators
   private:
       // The actual content 
}
```

In addition to the `SimpleContainer` - I want to create a `StrictContainer` which extends `SimpleContainer` semantically by enforcing rules on the content, but using the same content as an existing `SimpleContainer`instance.

```
class StrictContainer : public SimpleContainer {

     StrictContainer( const SimpleContainer& simple ) {
         // Check content in simple, and raise an exception 
         // if it is not valid.
     } 
}
```

Now - my problem is what kind of relationship there should be between the `SimpleContainer` and the `StrictContainer`:

**is-a**: 
seems natural; and that is what I have indicated with the inheritance, but then I will create a `StrictContainer` instance based on extending `SimpleContainer` instance post construction - is that possible?

**has-a** 
Alternatively I could implement it as a *has-a* relationship where the `StrictContainer` has a `SimpleContainer` member, but then I would need to implement all the accessors and iterators again in the `StrictContainer` and forward to the `SimpleContainer` implementation.

The container is *quite* large; and I would really not copy the content when creating the `StrictContainer`. I guess what I would like was a way to implement my own downcast operator:

```
SimpleContainer simple;
// Fill simpleContainer

{
    StrictContainer* strict = downcast<StrictContainer>( simple )
    ...
}
```

Where the `downcast<StrictContainer>` would call a method on the `StrictContainer` to verify the content of the `simple` input argument?

Comment: For what you use `StrictContainer`, for debugging, or their relation like `operator[]` and `at` in vector?

Comment: Why do you need the class `StrictContainer`? From your description it seems that it only serves as a validator for `SimpleContainer`. To me that sounds as a simple function call.

Comment: Most containers are movable so you may want to move a `SimpleContainer` into a `StrictContainer` to avoid the copy.

Comment: Seems to me that `StrictContainer` should be the base and `SimpleContainer` or other `RelaxedContainer`s should extend it!

Comment: Obviously you cannot enforce rules on content which is available through an interface that doesn't enforce these rules.

Comment: It's better for there to be no `is-a` relationship and instead the Strict container holds the functionality of the former.

Comment: @Eissa Or perhaps ContainerWithAbstractRules should be the base, and containers with concrete rules (including the trivial "anything goes" rule) should extend it.

Comment: Does the strict container have any other differences in the interface or behavior compared to the simple container? E.g. when adding elements to the strict container, shouled they also be checked?

Comment: I'm sorry I went completely silent on this - StackoverFlow complained about a missing JS library and I could not post anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, restating your requirements:

- The `StrictContainer` has the same interface as the `SimpleContainer`,
  with additions. (This implies an ***is-a*** relationship to the
  interface.)
- Intstantiating a new `StrictContainer` should not require
  copying the `SimpleContainer` content. (This implies decomposition using a handle.)

Assuming that the lifetime of the original `SimpleContainer` spans the `StrictContainer`, this sounds like the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). So, if you're willing to do a bit of decomposition -- how about defining an interface like this?

```
class MyInterface {
  // No contained state needed at all.
public:
  virtual ~MyInterface() {}
  virtual bool getThing1() const = 0;
  virtual int  getThing2() const = 0;
  // and so on...
};

class MyDecorator : public MyInterface {
    MyInterface &m_impl; // Could use a smart pointer, if available.
public:
    MyDecorator( MyInterface &impl ): m_impl(impl) {}
    bool getThing1() const override { return impl.getThing1(); }
    int  getThing2() const override { return impl.getThing2(); }
    // and so on...
};
```

Then your concrete implementation:

```
class SimpleContainer : public MyInterface {
    bool m_thing1;
    int  m_thing2;
        ... // All the real state goes here.
public:
        ... // All the interface methods go here.
};
```

Then, the `StrictContainer` is a lightweight container that retains a handle to the original `SimpleContainer`, instead of a full copy.

```
class StrictContainer : public MyDecorator {
    // Additional state, if needed.
public:
    StrictContainer( SimpleContainer &base ): MyDecorator(base) {}
    // Additional methods (like your additional validation method.
};
```

There's no need for a special "downcast operator", since you already need to call the constructor for `StrictContainer` and it already does everything you need.

```
SimpleContainer simple( ... );   // Construct as normal.
StrictContainer strict = simple; // Assuming no extra arguments needed.
```

Pretty simple.

And yes, you need to write the delegation operations for each method in the interface ***once*** in the decorator class. But you could define multiple variants of the `StrictContainer` class without having to implement them again (unless you ***want*** to override some of them).

Answer (score 2):

**is-a** would be a disaster.  Assume the rule is that `SimpleContainer` contains integers, and `StrictContainer` only contains odd integers.

```
StrictContainer strict;
SimpleContainer simple;
strict.insert(1);  // OK value is odd
simple.insert(2);  // OK simple doesn't check oddness.
SimpleContainer& sc = strict;  // Reference to base.
sc.SimpleContainer::insert(2);  // Uh-oh.  That will use the simple container version
                                // of insert (even in the presence of virtual functions)
                                // and will insert an invalid even number into `simple`.
```

You need **has-a**

Answer (score 2):

As a third option, I'd suggest a policy based approach as in the following example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>

template<typename T>
struct NoCheck {
    static bool isOk(T) {
        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct TheAnswer {
    static bool isOk(T t) {
        return false;
    }
};

template<>
struct TheAnswer<int> {
    static bool isOk(int t) {
        return t == 42;
    }
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class C = NoCheck>
struct SimpleContainer {
    bool add(T t) {
        if(C<T>::isOk(t)) {
            vec.push_back(t);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> vec{};
};

int main() {
    SimpleContainer<int> c1;
    assert(c1.add(42));
    assert(c1.add(0));
    SimpleContainer<int, TheAnswer> c2;
    assert(c2.add(42));
    assert(not c2.add(0));
}
```

If having a common interface is a requirement (it's not clear from the question), you can get it with a factory method and a type-erased internal class still based on a policy.

Comment: My prefered solution. Maybe you could add the implementation of a templated move constructor, as the OP wants to create a strict container from a simple container, without copying.

Comment: @MikeMB Sure. I'm not at home right now, but I'll add the move constructor as soon as possible.

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you're getting at, but I'm not sure you're answering the question that's been asked... And for a non-trivial `SimpleContainer`, this could be a lot of work to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer implementing something like this using a combination of Adapter and Strategy (Policy) pattern. You can decouple the StrictContainer (which is the adapter) from the underlying container holding the data entirely. Very similar to how std::queue is implemented as an adapter to another container (like vector). You can then parameterize the StrictContainer-adapter with whatever constraints you want to. Whenever you add an element to your container, it is checked whether the constraint is satisfied. If it is, the element is added to the underlying container, otherwise you can do whatever you prefer to (leave the container unchanged or throw an exception for instance).

```
template<typename T, typename Container, typename Constraint>
class StrictContainer
{
public:
    StrictContainer(const Container& container = {}, Constraint constraint = {})
       : container_(container), constraint_(constraint)
    {
        validateAll();
    }

    StrictContainer(Container&& container, Constraint constraint = {})
        : container_(std::move(container)), constraint_(constraint)
    {
        validateAll();
    }

    // container interface ...
    void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        if(!constraint_(value))
            throw WhateverException();
        container_.push_back(value);
    }

private:
    void validateAll()
    {
        for(const auto& value : container_)
        {
            if(!constraint_(value))
                throw WhateverException();
        }
    }

    Container container_;
    Constraint constraint_;
 };
```

You can then instantiate the StrictContainer like this:

```
StrictContainer<int, std::vector<int>, IsEvenConstraint<int>> myContainer;

myContainer.push_back(2);
myContainer.push_back(18);
myContainer.push_back(7); // throws
```

In this case the StrictContainer uses a std::vector as data store, but you could use whatever container you prefer (like your SimpleContainer). The constraints can then be implemented like this

```
template<typename T>
struct IsEvenConstraint
{
    bool operator()(const T& value)
    {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }
};
```

Depending on the classes of containers and constraints you like to support you might have to adjust the interface accordingly. Using variadic templates you can extend the StrictContainer to support multiple constraints. You can use a lambda for the constraint as well.

```
auto lessThanOne = [](float f) { return f < 1.0f; };
StrictContainer<float, std::vector<float>, decltype(lessThanOne)> myContainer2(std::vector<float>{}, lessThanOne);
myContainer2.push_back(0.1f);
myContainer2.push_back(1.7f); // throws
```